# Google Scripts: Populating Multi-Dimensional Array With Cell Values

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning the basics of Google Scripting after using VBA in Excel for many years, so please forgive the basic question.

I want to take a range of cells in my sheet using getValues() and then create a multi-element array.

Here is a simple example from my code:

```
  var gameInfo = [];
  gameInfo = gameMasterSheet.getRange(3, 3, 1, 9).getValues();
```

As you can see, the defined range is 9 cells in a single row.

My goal is to create an array from these 9 cells, and have each cell be accessible via a separate array element. However, it seems all 9 cell values are being inserted into gameInfo[0], and when I reference gameInfo[2] hoping to obtain the value of the third cell in the range, "undefined" is returned.

Is there a way to use getValues() to populate an array with separate elements? If so, how is this done? If not, what is a better alternative?

Thanks for any help you all can provide!

Comment: You could simply use var gameInfo = gameMasterSheet.getRange(3,3,1,9).getValues(), since getValues() returns a new 2D array.  In your case gameInfo is an array like [[cell1,cell2,cell3...]].  In you case to access cell2 simply use var cell = gameInfo[0][1];.  Javascript multi dimensional arrays can be though of an array of arrays. gameInfo[0] is an array.  If you had requested more rows gameInfo[1] would be the second row and gameInfo[1][2] would be the third cell of the second row.  Array indices are based on 0 so the first index is 0.

Comment: Thank you Ed - this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValues` returns a 2d array, even when it's a single row of cells. Think of it like this: `gameInfo[row - 1][column - 1]`, so the top left is `gameInfo[0][0]`.

All of your data is in `gameInfo` is in one row (`gameInfo[0]`), so the third element will be accessed as `gameInfo[0][2]` (row 1, column 3).

`gameInfo[2]` would be the third row, which is indeed outside of the range and `undefined`.

Also: to get just the values into an array from a 2d array, you could do this:

```
const values = [];
gameInfo.forEach(row => {
  row.forEach(column => {
    values.push(column);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See the script at the bottom of the [Simple Mail Merge Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) for some useful code to retrieve data.  Copy all the code from this comment down:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
/////////

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
```

Once you have, use getRowsData to retrieve the data as an array of objects.  If I understand you correctly, this will get you want you are after.

Karl S